# GLSL subroutines and shader uniforms. Why are my uniforms optimized out?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

Okay, I'm trying to use some of my shader uniform variables that is used inside of subroutine functions **only** (so there is no call to this variables outside of subroutine functions at all).

**Important part is**: I **don't** call this subroutine functions directly inside shader main, **instead** I have subroutine uniform array which I fill with glUniformSubroutinesuiv and use this syntax to call them:

```
    my_subroutines[i]();
```

My problem is that all of that uniform variables are optimized out.
What I've already checked:

- subroutine functions themselves are not optimized out (I found them
  via glGetActiveSubroutineName and they are here after shader
  linking). It's true always, even if there is no calls to them inside
  of shader main.
- If I call my subroutine function directly by it's name inside of shader main then uniforms are **not** optimized out (found them via glGetActiveUniform)

So, is this normal behaviour? How can I keep my uniform variables without doing some stupud things like that:

```
    void main()
    {
        vec4 color;

        //force use of uniform variables to prevent them be optimized out
        color += 0.0001*(uniform_variable0 + uniform_variable1 + ... + uniform_variableN);

        //call my subroutines here (that uses the same uniforms ... cmon glsl)
        color = subroutines_array[0](color);
        color = subroutines_array[1](color);
        ...
        color = subroutines_array[N](color);

        FragColor = color;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found that I'm doing it wrong:

```
    void main()
    {
        vec4 color;

        //so i never updated my color here, and that's why uniforms was cut out
        subroutines_array[0](color);
        subroutines_array[1](color);
        ...
        subroutines_array[N](color);

        FragColor = color;
    }
```